# validar que inputs dinámicos no estén vacios

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla HTML que se llena con registros de una BD, por otra parte la tabla HTML se inserta en otra tabla SQL diferente a la de la consulta que hago para llenar la tabla HTML, solo que a cada registro de la tabla HTML le he agregado un input ¿como puedo validar que no quede ningún input vació cuando se envié el formulario?, con el código de abajo procesa los input que ya estén llenos cuando se da clic sobre el botón guardar, pero lo que quiero es que no envié nada hasta que este todo lleno

```js
< script >

  $('#btnGuardar').click(function() {

    var text;
    var t = document.getElementById("trip-table"); //una tabla con id 
    var tdId = t.getElementsByClassName("idCliente"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdNombre = t.getElementsByClassName("nombre"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdCompras = t.getElementsByClassName("totalCompras"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdComision = t.getElementsByClassName("totalComision"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdAlcance = t.getElementsByClassName("alcance"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdMonto = t.getElementsByClassName("monto"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdConcepto = t.getElementsByClassName("concepto"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdFactura = t.getElementsByClassName("factura"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdMes = t.getElementsByClassName("mes"); // cada row tiene clase
    var tdAnio = t.getElementsByClassName("anio"); // cada row tiene clase


    for (var i = 0; i < tdId.length; i++) {
      var id = tdId[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr 
      var nombre = tdNombre[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr 
      var compras = tdCompras[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
      var comision = tdComision[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
      var alcance = tdAlcance[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
      var monto = tdMonto[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
      var concepto = tdConcepto[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
      //var factura = tdFactura[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
      var mes = tdMes[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
      var anio = tdAnio[i].innerHTML; //el contenido de cada tr
      var factura = document.getElementById('numeroFactura-' + [i]).value;
      var contador = 0
      if (factura != "") {

        $.ajax({
          //dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          url: "guardaAlcanceComisiones",
          data: {
            id: id,
            nombre: nombre,
            compras: compras,
            comision: comision,
            alcance: alcance,
            monto: monto,
            concepto: concepto,
            factura: factura,
            mes: mes,
            anio: anio
          },

          success: function(data) {
            $('#tabla').hide()
            $('#resultados').html(data);
          }
        });



      } else {
        alert("HAY CAMPOS VACIOS EN FILA " + id + "Nombre " + nombre);
      }
    }
  });
}); < /script>
```

este es mi tabla html con los input
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Espero poder ayudarte, saludos.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("enviar"); //Buscamos el Boton enviar

var b = document.querySelectorAll("input"); //Buscamos todos los inputs que existan en el documento
a.onclick=function(){ // le asignamos al boton enviar el evento onclick
var con = 0; //iniciamos una variable que incrementaremos si hay vacios.
  for(var c in b) //Iteramos todos los inputs que encontramos
  {
    var d = b[c];
    if(typeof d == "object")
    { 
      if(d.value == "" ) // Si existe algun campo vacio entonces incrementamos el contador
      {
        con ++;  
      }
    }
  }
  if(con >0)
  { 
    alert("Tienes "+con+ " campos vacios");}
  else{
    //Aqui coloca todo tu código
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="uno" name="aaa" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="dos" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="cuatro" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="cinco" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="siete" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="diez" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<input type="text" value="once" placeholder="vacio"><br/>
<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo así:

```
var input = $('input[type=text]');
if (input.val() == ""){
alert("un campo quedó vacío");
}else{
// Ejecutar código de inserción
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo lo resolvería de esta manera: https://jsfiddle.net/mayerson18/s9x1u5e0/

```
var encontro=false;
$('input[type=text]').each(function(indice,input){
  if ($(input).val() == ""){
    encontro=true;
  return false;//con esto detengo la corrida porque con un input que este vació no es necesario mirar los otros
  }
});
if(encontro)
  alert("Hay algun campo vacio");
```